# I have been using pyimgur to upload pictures and I would like to know how to delete them

Tags: python, imgur

I have been using this code to upload pictures to imgur:

```
import pyimgur

CLIENT_ID = "Your_applications_client_id"
PATH = "A Filepath to an image on your computer"

im = pyimgur.Imgur(CLIENT_ID)
uploaded_image = im.upload_image(PATH, title="Uploaded with PyImgur")
print(uploaded_image.title)
print(uploaded_image.link)
print(uploaded_image.size)
print(uploaded_image.type)
```

I'm using the client ID from my Imgur account, but after I upload them they wont't appear among my user photos.

Do you know where are they stored and how can I delete them?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was:
print(uploaded_image.deletebash)
and once you get that code:
imgur.com/delete/